# Why are these types of videos called 'slander'?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Search 'slander' in Youtube and you will get tons of meme-like videos with 'slander' in their titles. For example, here is a screenshot of [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiwNAbqX-Ws&ab_channel=DepreScionZ) *Job Slander*.
[image]

Why are these types of videos called *slanders*? Is it because they are full of stereotypes? But a stereotype is not necessarily a defamation. Besides, according to [this Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/legal/personal-injury/libel-vs-slander/),

> The big difference between libel vs slander is the form in which the untrue statement is made.
>
> - Libel occurs when a false statement is published in written form and does harm to a victim
> - Slander occurs when a false statement is made in oral form and does harm to a victim

It also gives a list of what materials would count as a libel.

> Libel occurs when a false statement is published in any type of written form. This can include print, writing, pictures, or digital communications such as:
>
> - Books
> - Magazines
> - Newspapers
> - Newsletters
> - Social media
> - Websites
> - Blogs
>
> If there is a physical (or digital) representation of the false statement, then it is libel.

So, a video of that sort should be libel rather than slander. Why are they still named *slander*?

Comment: The video carries that title which is the first situation in the video. It does not refer to all the other ones depicted in the video, each of which has its own title. I've explained how I understand this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The video is not called job slander. That is a supra-title in the video, among many others. The video shows a series of situations. That one shows a restaurant worker taking stuff from the garbage and putting it in the food to be served. Some idiot who made the video decided to call it that. It makes no sense since there is no spoken language at all. Slander, is, after all, a spoken not a written thing.

**But, let's say someone says**, That server is a "shit server", that would be outrageously sardonic and true metaphorically but false actually. There is no actual shit. A shit server means one who is no good OR one who serves shit. Or if someone says: That is a shit job. Same idea.

That title is just the first one that appears in the video. There are many others. So, the poster just posted it under that first situation depicted in the video.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common error/misconception.

Forbes' definition is wrong, though they almost corrected themselves with the list.
The definition is "permanent [public] record" not "in writing" [or written form]. In writing used to be sufficient definition, but it no longer is, since the advent of television news reporting.

The people making the videos obviously believe Forbes' main headline. Most people do.

Comment: @Lambie - would you care to actually look this up rather than just take a swipe at me [again]? It is a very common misconception, passed on like it it is some sort of gospel. The difference is 'permanent vs ephemeral'. Reading through the actual statute is a nightmare, so you need to look this up on law practise pages to get the true distinction in 'human-readable' language. Forbes do in fact qualify this further down the article, but people only read the headlines & perpetuate the myth.

Comment: @Lambie - again, you're just quoting the 'headline' [I don't care whether or not it's the page title, that's not the point]. The point is the flat statement as outlined is 'not true in law', yet most people [including, apparently, you] think it is. It is a misconstruction of the actual law, perpetuated by many. The legal [civil] charge is 'defamation', not libel or slander, which are merely sub-divisions. These have become newspaper headlinese.

Comment: @Lambie - again, you are just perpetuating the myth. Please look it up, properly. I'm done. I have done my homework on this subject in the past. I'm not going to find all the factual references for you now.

Comment: I have removed all my comments as I do not like being told I am taking a swipe at someone. I find your answer to be very misleading. And to say this "The people making the videos obviously believe Forbes' main headline."  is misleading. It was the OP that is using the Forbes article not the video makers.